# HTACCESS friendly urls with parameters 2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a little problem.

redirect in .htaccess from:

```
domena.pl/index.php?galeria
```

to

```
domena.pl/galeria
```

work fine but now I need to redirect

```
domena.pl/index.php?galeria=Inne
```

to

```
domena.pl/galeria/inne
```

too and this give me redirect loop.

My .htaccess now is:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domena.pl(.*) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domena.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?([^\s=]+?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z-]+)$ index.php?$1=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what i have done on my site:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /view.php?id=1 to /view/id/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.php\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]

# internal forward from /view/id/1 to /view.php?id=1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```